# How to inherit permissions in SharePoint 2013 through Rest Api?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest

In Sharepoint 2013, there is a rest API to break permissions and add permissions to the object, but is there an rest Api to inherit permissions on the object again?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this endpoint url to reset the permission, this will reset the permissions which means it will inherit the parent permission.

```
url : <site URL>/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('<list name>')/items('<item id>')/resetroleinheritance
```

The above URL will reset the permission at the item level, you may implement the same for list or site level.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to `breakroleinheritance` you can use `resetroleinheritance` endpoint

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.resetroleinheritance.aspx